# Unity3d Animation just doesn't show up sometimes

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have simple pop-up text animator with four attached animations (heal text animation, crit heal animation, damage animation and crit damage snimation).

The animator changes animations on a trigger received from a simple script.

```
public static void PopUpTextInstantiator(int text, Transform location, bool crit)
{
     Initialize();
     Debug.Log("Instancing POPUP with VALUE" +text +" and CRIT is "+ crit);
     PopUpText instanceclone = Instantiate(popupText);
     Vector2 screenPosition = new Vector2(location.position.x + Random.Range(-.5f, .5f), location.position.y + Random.Range(0.1f, 0.5f));

     instanceclone.transform.SetParent(canvas.transform, false);
     if (text < 0 && crit == true)
     {
         instanceclone.GetComponentInChildren<Animator>().SetTrigger("CritDamage");
         Destroy(instanceclone, 1.2f);
     }
     else if (text < 0 && crit == false)
     {
         instanceclone.GetComponentInChildren<Animator>().SetTrigger("Damage");
         Destroy(instanceclone, 1.2f);
     }
     else if (text > 0 && crit == false)
     {

         instanceclone.GetComponentInChildren<Animator>().SetTrigger("Heal");
         Debug.Log("IM WORKING POPUP INSTANTIATOR NON CRIT");
         Destroy(instanceclone, 1.2f);
     }
     else if (text > 0 && crit == true)
     {
         instanceclone.GetComponentInChildren<Animator>().SetTrigger("CritHeal");
         Destroy(instanceclone, 1.2f);
     }

     //Debug.Log("Instancing POPUP at COORD VALUE" + location.transform.position);
     //instanceclone.transform.position = screenPosition;
     instanceclone.transform.position = screenPosition;
     instanceclone.SetText(text);
 }
```

There is problem SOMETIMES (not always but quite often) where the animation (especially "hea animation") just doesn't shown up. I see instanced parent but no animation. Same problem in the build. Crit Heal animation is always shown correctly, damage some times doesn't show, and simple Heal doesn't show very often. I just don't understand why and where the error is - the script is essentially the same. The animation by itself is working perfectly.

Comment: Try creating a minimized test script that can reproduce your problem. Then debug it.

Comment: Could there possibly be more than one Animator component in the prefab you're cloning, and sometimes it sets the trigger on the wrong one?